# Video background overlaying section

Tags: css, html, video, z-index

So i have this website that has 5 sections with a min-height of 100vh. On the first one there is a video (with the html5 video tag) that i'm using as background for this section. 
The problem is that this video is staying on top of the 2nd section and hiding part of it's content.

I tried increasing the z-index on the 2nd section but it doesn't change anything.
What can i do?

```
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.video {

   position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  z-index: 1;
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}




<section id="first">
 <!-- NAVBAR HERE -->

<video id="my-video" class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" width="300" height="150">
        <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video><!-- /video -->


    <div class="container">


    <div class="row logo" style="z-index:100;">
        <div class="col-md-12"><img src="img/logo-cinza.png" class="img-responsive logo-grad" /></div> 
    </div>



    <div class="row botao" style="z-index:100;">
        <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center;"><a href="contact.html"><button class="btn btn-lg" id="button"><p>Available for hire</p></button></a></div> 
    </div>




  <div class="row chevron-down" style="z-index:100;">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <p style="text-align:center; font-size:0.8em; color:#c3c0c0 ">Click to see more awesomness</p> 
        <a href="#second" class="smoothScroll"><img class="img-responsive seta" width="40px" src="img/seta-cinza.png" alt="Discover More Awesomness" /></a>
      </div>
</div>



    </div>

   </section> 
<section id="second">..
```

Comment: Please post more markup to help demonstrate the issue. It sounds to me like a simple overflow but without additional information I can't be sure

Comment: @NathanDawson just edited

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the overlap is caused by the video overflowing the container. There's not enough CSS / markup in your question to be more specific but I've put together a simple example below.

In the example I'm also placing the content inside a div and setting that to relative positioning with a z-index to ensure it overlays the video.

HTML:

```
<div class="section-1 video-section section">
    <video id="my-video" class="video" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" width="300" height="150">
        <source src="img/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>

    <div class="content">Here goes my content</div>
</div>

<div class="section-2 section">
    Put some content here for section 2.
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.section {
    min-height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.video {
    height: auto;
    left: 50%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    width: auto;
}

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work.. Still the same problem :/
You want me to write more code?